# Parsing Logs from multiple servers with different syslog format in fluentd

Tags: fluentd

We have some windows servers, linux server and some switches, each group sends his independent syslog format to the fluentd syslog server.
which is better:

- Each group send his logs to a certain fluentd tcp port, so that each group will have his logs parsed inside an individual source tag

`

```
<source>    # for linux
 type syslog
 **port 12000**
 <parse>
  <grok>
  </grok>
 </parse>
</source> 

<source>    # for windows
 type syslog
 **port 12001**
 <parse>
  <grok>
  </grok>
 </parse>
</source> 

<source>   # for some switches
 type syslog
 **port 12002**
 <parse>
  <grok>
  </grok>
 </parse>
</source>
```

`

or

- All groups send their logs to the flentd syslog server and the parsing will be done inside one source tag

`

```
<source>
 @type tail             
 path /var/log/syslog   
 tag test
 <parse>
  <grok>
    pattern
  </grok>
  <grok>
    pattern
  </grok>
  <grok>
    pattern
  </grok>
 <parse>
</source>
```

`

we are using EFK for log monitoring, Please feel free to recommend a better solution if available

thanks